# Understanding the output of println("${Thread.currentThread()}")

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

When I print a coroutine thread out

```
println("${Thread.currentThread()}")
```

It will show

```
Thread[DefaultDispatcher-worker-1 @coroutine#4,5,main]
```

I know that

- `DefaultDispatcher-worker-1` is the Thread currently running in
- `@coroutine#4` is the coroutine name
- `5` is the priority of the thread it is running in
- `main` -- what is this referring to? the launching thread?

I don't understand what `main` is for, although I know that refers to the `main` thread.

Is it the parent thread? (I doubt so, as I try using a non-main parent thread, it still show `main`) 
Is it the launching thread? 
If not, what is it?

Comment: Could it be the name of the function it was launched in?

Comment: No, the function is not named `main`. I write it in a unit test and Android code, which doesn't have `main` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By checking the `toString()` function of the `Thread`, found that

```
    public String toString() {
        ThreadGroup group = getThreadGroup();
        if (group != null) {
            return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                           group.getName() + "]";
        } else {
            return "Thread[" + getName() + "," + getPriority() + "," +
                            "" + "]";
        }
    }
```

Looks like it is the thread group name.

Comment: main as a thread group name, I guess it's a little confusing, main normally refers to the main thread or a UI thread for android specifically, here in this case it's a default dispatcher, and naming it has a main thread !!